# How to find the closest distance from the origin to the $x^2-z^2-1=0$by using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus

I solved this question without using the Lagrange Multipliers without a problem, but when I wanted to solve it again by the Lagrange ,I found some problem.

My attempt is

$$d^2=f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$$
so the Lagrange multipliers is
$$L=x^2+y^2+z^2+\lambda _1(x^2-z^2-1)$$
now I will derive the function to the variables which are $(x,y,z,\lambda _1)$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=2x+2x\lambda _1=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=2y=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}=2z-2\lambda _1z-=0$$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda _1}=(x^2-z^2-1)=0$$

after that I dont know how to continue. Any help, thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second equation gives $y=0$

The first and third equations give you either

$$\lambda_1=-1, z=0, x^2=1$$

or

$$\lambda_1=+1, x=0, z^2=-1$$

which has no real solutions for $z$ so the min distance is from the origin to $(\pm1 , 0, 0) $ which equals $1$ unit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve sistem of equations that you got (at least you have to find values of $x$, $y$ and $z$).

Solutions $(\hat x,\hat y,\hat z)$ are candidates for the point you are looking for, so you have to compute all distances to find out, which is the nearest to the origin among them.